# How to hide radio button until something happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

So I want to hide a radio button until my form is filled out but I don't know how.  I tried .hide(); and that worked when I put it outside of my .submit function but doesn't work inside of it.  This is using jquery and bootstrap.

Here is a small version of the JS I have ('agree' is the radio button):

```
$('myForm').submit(function(e){
    var firstName = $('first-name').val();
    var pattern = /^$/;
    var error = '';
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('agree');

    if(pattern.test(firstName)){
       error += 'Error: enter first name.\n';
    }

    if(error.length != 0){
        alert(error);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

I want to hide the radio button until the first name part of the form is filled out then the radio button will appear.

Comment: Set radio button's CSS to `display:none`. Then use jQuery's bind on input for the form field. When they start typing in it then set the radio button's css to `display:block;` See the following links to see other examples I have done on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551833/javascript-call-function-oninput/33553683#33553683  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544127/check-if-the-page-was-reload

Comment: This seems like something you could use angular for pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you, but I actually don't want to use css for this.  I guess I should have mentioned I am using jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: CSS is the simple way to hide an object, either with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`. I believe jQuery has a function hide() for this...

Comment: ah @Guy got you, I'll modify my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I would use plain JavaScript for this:

```
<input type="text" name="first-name" value="" onchange="document.getElementById('agree').style.display = (this.value == '' ? 'block' : 'none' );"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="Agree" style="display:none"/>
```

**Edit:** 
Other ways to do this is to use onkeydown, onkeyup or onblur instead of onchange

Answer (score 0):

Put an id in your radio like this :

```
<input type="radio" id="rad" />
```

Then hide it like this using jquery :

```
$('#rad').hide();
```

Then an example of how you can make it show when something happens would go a bit like this :

```
If ($('#something') > 10) {
    $('#rad').show();
}
```

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using jquery... http://jsfiddle.net/wa8rxj43/2/

HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="name" class="name">
 <input class="not-display" id="somecheck" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#somecheck').hide();

$("#name").bind({
    'input':function(){
        if(this.value.length > 0)
        {
            $('#somecheck').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#somecheck').hide();
        }

    }
});
```

Edit: Removed CSS per OP's request.